# New bronze badge for reading tag wiki

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki, badge-request

As a means to encourage new users to look at tag wiki and become aware of them, I suggest that we add a new bronze badge for reading `x` different entries of tag wiki (which has *some content*), where `x` can be from 1 to 5.

I personally prefer the number to be 5, so as to increase their chance of running into some good content (well, not all tag wiki are good anyway). When they have found out the usefulness of tag wiki, hopefully, they will check them out later.

Comment: good idea but the only issue is new users don't care about badges or reputation.

Comment: Sounds pretty reasonable to me, it was months before I read a tag wiki, where as I immediately read the about page (although it's entirely possible I just scrolled it....). @ZaheerAhmed, I think that's completely unnecessary, what if you're only interested in SQL questions? I doubt I've even read 50 of the on-hover summaries.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed: With 5, I am already worried about whether they manage to reach that number within the first few days on SO. Unless they check out the badge page, they are unlikely to know about the feature to "randomly" get the badge.